# Charts not visible on the page

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

**EDIT**
Finally figured it out. You need to add this to your project. Probably a good thing to document:

http://www.jqplot.com/

No chart is displaying on the page, even though the code of the javascript etc is available through Firebug.

I am using Mojarra and Primefaces 3

> ```
>        <h:form>
>             <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />
>
>             <p:pieChart value="#{distributionChart.pieModel}" legendPosition="w"
>                         title="Interactive Pie Chart" style="width:400px;height:300px">
>                 <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{distributionChart.itemSelect}" update="growl" />
>             </p:pieChart>
>
>         </h:form>
> ```

Backing bean

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class DistributionChart implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private QuestionServiceBean questionService;

    private CartesianChartModel categoryModel;
    private PieChartModel pieModel;
    private List<QuestionCategoryDistribution> distribution;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        distribution = questionService.getQuestionCategoryDistribution();
        createPieModel();
    }

    public void itemSelect(ItemSelectEvent event) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Item selected",
                "Item Index: " + event.getItemIndex() + ", Series Index:" + event.getSeriesIndex());

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }

    public PieChartModel getPieModel() {
        return pieModel;
    }

    private void createPieModel() {
        pieModel = new PieChartModel();

        for (QuestionCategoryDistribution obj : distribution) {
            pieModel.set(obj.getCategoryDescription(), obj.getNumberOfQuestions());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should answer to your own question and accept the answer, in order for future readers to know the solution and in order to mark the question as answered. Please try to elaborate a bit more on what must be done.

Comment: I will, I only need to get all things done first:)